# Is there a countably infinite closed interval in the lattice of topologies?

Tags: set-theory, gn.general-topology, infinite-combinatorics, lattice-theory

Is there an interval of the form $[\sigma,\tau]$ in the lattice of topologies on some set $X$ such that $|[\sigma,\tau]| = \aleph_0$?
In other words, do there exist two topologies $\sigma$ and $\tau$ on $X$ such that there are a countably infinite number of topologies on $X$ that are finer than $\sigma$ and coarser than $\tau$?

I can find intervals like this of size $n$ for every finite $n > 0$, and intervals of size $\mathfrak{c}$. But I don't see how to obtain closed intervals of any intermediate size. I have a proof (well, an idea for a proof) that if $|[\sigma,\tau]| = \aleph_0$, then $\sigma$ cannot be a Hausdorff topology. Other than this, though, I can't seem to say much of anything about this question.

Comment: Doesn't it work if we take $\mathbb{N}$ with the (highly non-Hausdorff) topologies $\sigma = \{[2n,+\infty) : n\in\mathbb{N}\}$ and $\tau = \{[n,+\infty) : n\in\mathbb{N}\}$, or am I missing something ?

Comment: Ah, of course not, I misunderstood the use of "interval" in this context, assuming that it should be a totally ordered set.

Answer (score 5):

The special case where $\sigma=\{\emptyset,X\}$ is the trivial topology is easy to resolve. In this case, if $\tau$ is finite, then the interval $[\sigma,\tau]$ is finite. If $\tau$ is infinite, then there must exist an $\omega$-chain
$T_0\subsetneq T_1\subsetneq T_2\subsetneq\cdots$
of nonempty, proper open sets in $\tau$ or a dual $\omega$-chain of nonempty, proper open sets in $\tau$. Assuming the former, for any nonempty subset $I\subseteq \omega$ let ${\mathcal B}_I=\{T_i\;|\;i\in I\}$ be a basis for a subtopology of $\tau$. Since $I\neq J$ implies that ${\mathcal B}_I$ and ${\mathcal B}_J$ generate different subtopologies of $\tau$, we get at least $\mathfrak c$ topologies in the interval $[\sigma,\tau]$.

Comment: Does this really work?  If $I = \{1\}$ and $J = \{0,1\}$, don't ${\mathcal{B}}_I$ and ${\mathcal{B}}_J$ both generate $T_1$?

Comment: @Anonymous: The topology generated by your ${\mathcal B}_I$ is $\{\emptyset, T_1, X\}$. The topology generated by your ${\mathcal B}_J$ is $\{\emptyset, T_0, T_1, X\}$. These are different.

Comment: Oh, right. I misunderstood what you were saying. Thanks.

Comment: Interesting -- thanks! I'm starting to suspect that the answer to my question might be negative.